# How to add a role to the ec2 instance created by packer's amazon-ebs buiilder

Tags: packer, hashicorp

Packer ebs-builder spins up an ec2 instance. Is it possible to attach a role to this ec2 instance? I want the role so that I can run some AWS cli commands in the user_data portion.